# Transfer part of the dom on page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple jquery mobile application in which every page has the following structure:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">...</div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">...</div>
    <div class="content-secondary">...</div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

The `content-secondary` is a left sidebar, much like the jquery mobile documentation.  This secondary content never changes but it can be very large and complex (expensive to reload on every page).  I would like to **move** the same dom element from page to page as it transitions, and not have to include it on every page like the jqm documentation.  I only need to load it when it doesn't exist and then move it with every page transition.  Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert `HTML` `content` in to your `page` in a `pagebeforecreate` handler.

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be on the page transition event.  Because on pageveforecreate I would have to copy from the currently showing page to the new one, when I want to transfer it.

Comment: Putting it in `pagetransition` will result in the component making a flash appearance on the screen. So I tend to add any new `HTML` `content` in the `pagebeforecreate` so that it also gets enhanced by JQM.